# Why do nitrile gloves turn yellow from sweaty hands?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, nitriles

When I take off my nitrile gloves after some hours in the lab, the inside of them has turned yellow. This happens especially in the regions around joints.

I suspect this is due to a reaction between some compounds in the sweat and the nitrile, but I couldn't find any definite answer online about what the responsible mechanism for this is.

What exactly is reacting and turning yellow?

Comment: Are the gloves powdered? If so, it might be an accumulation of the powder lubricant.